# NestJS Mongoose Request-Scoped Connection Error/Fail

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, requestscope, nestjs-mongoose

Imagine for example: I've got two databases with same objects/models but for different Organisations. And based on request I need to select correct DB to connect. I use this in `app.module.ts`:

```js
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  useClass: MyMongooseConfigService,
})
```

`MyMongooseConfigService` looks something like this:

```js
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class MyMongooseConfigService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST)
    private readonly req: Request,
    private http: HttpService,
  ) {}

  async createMongooseOptions(): Promise<MongooseModuleOptions> {
    const param = req.headers.mysecretheader;
    const foundDb = await this.http.get(`http://my-web-server/param/${param}`);
    const dbName = foundDb.dbName;
    const uri = `mongodb+srv://connection_data/${dbName}`;
    console.log(`uri for stackoverflow:`, uri);
    return { uri };
  }
}
```

I've got  a web server which returns this Organisation object by HTTP which is stored in 3-rd DB with a structure like:

```js
{
  param: string;
  dbName: string;
}
```

So, when I get request, I have the `param` by which to search `dbName` in Organisations' DB on my web server.

I expect DB connection to use this `MyMongooseConfigService` per request and every connection will go to appropriate DB. But that's not the case. I've got for example `UserService` which gets users from correct Organisation. It looks something like:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<User> 
  ) {}

  async getUsers() {
    console.log(`dbName for stackoverflow:`, this.userModel.db.name)
    const users = await this.userModel.find();
  }
}
```

The resulting users don't belong to correct organisation. So, what's wrong?

During initialisation mongoose make a connection attempt without actual request, and finds first available `dbName`. I've even asked about this "init" connection in official [NestJS Discord channel](https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/1128268154901115012/1128632279032410203), there I've got the answer: `the assumption is, you know what databases are supposed to be in use at the time the app starts`.

Web server that returns `dbName` by `param` makes search in DB like `organisationModel.findOne({})` if no `param` passed (I guess, it's serialisation when I make a request to web server) and it returns first Organisation in the list. So if I have in Organisations DB objects like:

`{ param: '1234', dbName: 'org-1' }` and `{ param: '5678', dbName: 'org-2' }`

the first found Organisation's `dbName` will always be `org-1`. If I remove all Organisations and add them in another order, the first found will always be `org-2`

And I've made `console.log's for stackoverflow` on purpose in `UserService` and in `MyMongooseConfigService`. When I make a request with param `5678` I've got in logs:

```
uri for stackoverflow: mongodb+srv://connection_data/org-2
dbName for stackoverflow: org-1
```

This is the actual problem: **connection uri** in `MyMongooseConfigService` **is correct** every time, but the **model always returns** the `db.name` **of the first connected DB**.  TS says that `model.db.name` is "`The name of the database this connection points to`".

Maybe I've done something wrong, forgot something? Can anyone help/guide?

I've tried to add `@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })` to `UserService`. Seems like nothing has changed, because it all should bubble up to controller and to the request.